# How do I remove outlier rows

Tags: r, filter, outliers

```
    ap_lo          cholesterol gluc      smoke     alco      active   
 Min.   :  -70.00   1:52385     1:59479   0:63831   0:66236   0:13739  
 1st Qu.:   80.00   2: 9549     2: 5190   1: 6169   1: 3764   1:56261  
 Median :   80.00   3: 8066     3: 5331                                
 Mean   :   96.63                                                      
 3rd Qu.:   90.00                                                      
 Max.   :11000.00
```

If you notice, `ap_lo` has outliers on both ends. They are data entry errors. ap_lo is Diastolic Blood Pressure. It shouldn't be either negative or that high.

I want to remove them (and possibly find more). How would I go about removing their index in R?

The following code is *not* the answer:

```
CV$ap_lo <- CV[-c(which.min(CV$ap_lo))]
```

Comment: We don't know what your data means, so we can't say what should be an outlier. Is the data normally distributed?  Is it supposed to always be positive?   Do you have some rules that would define what is an outlier?

Comment: They are data entry errors. `ap_lo` is Diastolic Blood Pressure. It shouldn't be either negative or that high.

Answer (score 0):

One of many valid approaches is to use the non-parametric outliers returned by `boxplot`.

let `v` be your values: `v <- c(-100, rnorm(50), 100)`
and `stats` be the statistics returned by `boxplot`ing (w/o actual need for plotting): `stats <- boxplot(v, plot = FALSE)`, then you can remove the outliers (according to boxplot standards) like: `v_without_outliers <- setdiff(v, stats$out)`, or short:

```
v_without_outliers <- 
    setdiff(v, (v |> boxplot(plot = FALSE))$out)
```

related:

- [outlier detection with R](https://statsandr.com/blog/outliers-detection-in-r/)
- package {[outliers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/outliers/index.html)}

Comment: This returns 77 observations. My dataset has 70,000 observations, however.

Comment: `with(CV, setdiff(ap_lo, (ap_lo |> boxplot(plot = FALSE))$out))` returns 77 out of 70k observations indeed? It would be helpful to see a `histogram` of `CV$ap_lo`.